# Table border style lost after uploaded on Gdoc

Tags: ms-word, google-drive-api, google-docs

We are now working on upload word document on Google Docs by .NET. We have an template which contains tables, we set border style of tables to none, then all the borders are invisible. But after we uploaded it on Google Docs, the borders appears in black. We tried upload the template to Google Docs manually, the borders appear too. So I think our code is correct, does the Google Docs API allow us to change the style of table border  after convert .docx to Google Doc? Or any solution to keep the borders invisible?

I've tried to make the table border to white (the paper color), then the borders is hidden while I upload it to Google Docs without conversion. But while I try to edit it, the table border appears again. I guess that's because Google viewer convert the .docx to GDoc while I try to edit the .docx document.

I've tried to set table border to none in Word, but the borders still appears after conversion. Is this a bug of Google document conversion? It should set the border to zero while the table border was set to none in Word, but it doesn't do that. Is there anybody can help me on this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried a border size of zero?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, there is no way of modifying the document content after uploading. You may, however find better fidelity by converting to HTML or PDF and uploading those formats.

Otherwise, you should raise a bug report on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aAPI-DocumentsList), so that the conversion can be improved.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added this issue on issue tracker, the id is 3090. Hope this be fixed soon.

Comment: The issue URL: http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3090.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your problem, but it's a work around that I'm using currently, by setting the border colour to white it no longer displays the black borders.